# TFS API Slowness

Tags: vb.net, tfs

I am writing an extension for Visual Studio 2013/Team Foundation Server 2012.

I have a user control with a treeview and a listview.  The treeview shows the branches within the team project selected, as well as all sub-folders.  The listview lists the files contained within the selected folder as well as some basic information for each like the last check-in date, the last user to make a change, etc.

I am first pulling the items in the selected folder and then getting the latest changset for each item:

```
Public Sub GetSourceControlDetailDefault(ByVal strFolder As String, Optional recursionType__1 As RecursionType = RecursionType.OneLevel)
            SourceControlListViewItems.Clear()
            Dim serverItem As String = strFolder + "/"
            Dim itemSet As ItemSet = Nothing

            Dim spec As New ItemSpec(serverItem, recursionType__1)
            itemSet = TfsShared.Instance.Vcs.GetItems(spec, VersionSpec.Latest, DeletedState.NonDeleted, ItemType.File, False)

            For Each item In itemSet.Items
                Dim chgDetail As Changeset = GetDetails(item.ChangesetId.ToString(), item.ServerItem.ToString())
                SourceControlListViewItems.Add(New ItemClass(item, chgDetail))                        
            Next

        End Sub

Public Function GetDetails(ByVal cID As String, iName As String) As Changeset   
            Dim serverItem As String = iName
            Dim latest As Changeset

            Dim version As New ChangesetVersionSpec(cID)

            latest = TfsShared.Instance.Vcs.QueryHistory(serverItem, VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.None, Nothing, version, _
                                                     version, 1, False, False, False).Cast(Of Changeset)().First()

            Return latest
        End Function

Public Property SourceControlListViewItems() As ObservableCollection(Of ItemClass)
            Get
                Return m_SourceControlListViewItems
            End Get
            Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of ItemClass))
                m_SourceControlListViewItems = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_SourceControlListViewItems As ObservableCollection(Of ItemClass)
```

My ItemClass implements INotifyPropertyChanged and has the get/set for the details I'm pulling.

This all works - I get the information I want displayed correctly.  The problem is that it's extremely slow.  A folder with 20 items takes 8 seconds to load.  A folder with 129 items takes 40 seconds to load.  And we have folders with far more than 129 items.

If I load just the items it is very fast.  It is only once I pull the changeset for each item that it slows down.  Unfortunately most of the information I want displayed is not contained within the item.

Is there anything I can do to make this more efficient?  At this speed it is unusable.

Thanks!

Comment: you are doing a network call in your foreach loop... hence why you are experiencing such "performance" problems when really, it isn't a performance problem - just the fact that you are calling out to a service.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to obtain the information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ahmed ilyas for getting me to think about this in a different way.

After pulling the itemSet I am now getting all changesets for the selected folder in one query and storing them in a local variable.  I can then pull the appropriate changeset locally.  Even a folder with over 600 files now takes only 3 seconds to load.

```
Public Sub GetSourceControlDetailDefault(ByVal strFolder As String, Optional recursionType__1 As RecursionType = RecursionType.OneLevel)
            SourceControlListViewItems.Clear()
            Dim serverItem As String = strFolder + "/"
            Dim itemSet As ItemSet = Nothing

            Dim spec As New ItemSpec(serverItem, recursionType__1)
            itemSet = TfsShared.Instance.Vcs.GetItems(spec, VersionSpec.Latest, DeletedState.NonDeleted, ItemType.File, False)

            GetFolderChangesets(strFolder)

            For Each item In itemSet.Items
                Dim chgDetail As Changeset = GetChangesetDetails(item.ChangesetId.ToString())
                    SourceControlListViewItems.Add(New ItemClass(item, chgDetail ))
                End If
            Next

        End Sub

Public Sub GetFolderChangesets(ByVal strFolder As String)  
            Dim serverItem As String = strFolder + "/*"
            Dim spec As New ItemSpec(serverItem, RecursionType.Full)
            Dim versionFrom As New ChangesetVersionSpec(1)

            m_folderChangesets = TfsShared.Instance.Vcs.QueryHistory(serverItem, VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, Nothing, versionFrom, _
                                                                   VersionSpec.Latest, Integer.MaxValue, False, False, False).Cast(Of Changeset)().ToList()

        End Sub

Public Property FolderChangesets() As List(Of Changeset)
            Get
                Return m_folderChangesets
            End Get
            Set(value As List(Of Changeset))
                m_folderChangesets = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_folderChangesets As List(Of Changeset)
```